# using google oauth to authenticate onto my private website but only allow certain users to login

Tags: google-oauth

I have a public facing private web application I would like to protect using google oauth. I have many passwords recorded on bitwarden. I dont want another one if I can help it. It basically allows to remotely control my burgular alarm.

Is there a way I can use google oauth but users still need my authorization to access the website. Otherwise anyone with a Google account can access my site which I definately want to avoid. Also it should be free because am cheap.

Comment: why has someone voted to close my question. I was once told there are no stupid questions. just stupid answers